# C#: What is the preferred way to handle this error?

Tags: c#

I have a class 'Hand' that consists of two playing cards as below:

```
public class Card
{
    public char r, s;

    public Card(char rank, char suit)
    {
        r = rank;
        s = suit;
    }
}

public class Hand
{
    public Card c1, c2;

    public Hand(Card one, Card two)
    {
        c1 = one;
        c2 = two;
    }
}
```

In a 52 card deck we can't have two identical cards. How should I deal with an error where I accidentally instance a class with two identical cards, e.g (Ah, Ah)?

Thanks, Ash

Comment: How are you generating these hands? Perhaps they should come from a valid deck of 52 cards so that this error never occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to create an Exception structure where you can identify the error in a more clear way to be able to handle it.

For example, if you are creating a game that is likely to have different business rules, most business rules exceptions should be inherited from a base GameRuleException. In this case, in your scenario I would be creating a specific Exception like HandCardException that inherits GameRuleException.

The importance of having this hierarchy is that when you catching the exception you can be sure that the error is coming from a game rule instead of a connection issue for example.

See examples below - note I haven't tested the code it is just to illustrate

```
public class GameRuleException : Exception
{

    public GameException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class HandCardException : GameRuleException
{

    public HandCardException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class Card
{
    public int r;

    public char s;
    public Card(int rank, char suit)
    {
        r = rank;
        s = suit;
        if (rank > 13 || rank < 1) {
            throw new GameRuleException("The card rank must be between 1 and 13");
        }
    }
}

public class Hand
{
    public Card c1;

    public Card c2;
    public Hand(Card one, Card two)
    {
        //Basic validation

        if (one == null || two == null) {
            throw new HandCardException("Each hand needs at least two cards");
        }

        if (one == two) {
            throw new HandCardException("Repeated cards are found.");
        }

        //Allows creating the instance

        c1 = one;
        c2 = two;

    }
}
```

Then the application that is using these classes, when could handle these exceptions correctly ... for example:

```
try {
    Hand hand = new Hand(card1, card2);
} catch (GameRuleException ex) {
    //Handle the error by showing the error in a label ... 
    ErrorLabel.Text = ex.message;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Any other exception will log
    //Trace.Error(ex)
    //And maybe throw back the exception... ?
    //Throw
}
```

That is just an example of how you can use custom exceptions to be able to handle them more appropriately.

Comment: Just a note on my answer, I am discussing how to handle exceptions and not the design of the suggested sample.

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't the deck handle that?  For example you could have a pinochle deck and a regular deck that would enforce the card instance restrictions.

Comment: You can have different combinations of hands active at once, say Ah Ad, Ah Ac, Ah As. You just can't have the same combination twice. (In this specific case)

Comment: RedDeckWins: Sure, but a user of the Hand class could still do something stupid such as pass the same card instance for both parameters.

Comment: This is a valid point, I wasn't looking at it in terms of Ash providing some sort of card/deck library.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing an ArgumentException would be an acceptable solution. From MSDN:

> ArgumentException is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the passed arguments does not meet the parameter specification of the called method.

Of course, you will have to catch the exception somewhere higher up in your code and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: I don't think it is legitimate to handle this exception. Catching an ArgumentException is a code smell. If you're tossing in invalid arguments, why are you trying to fix this with catch, instead of passing valid arguments? I'd say throw the exception if the arguments are invalid, but don't catch it.

Comment: ArgumentException should only be used for invalid arguments. "Queen of Diamonds" (for example) is a valid argument for the method.

Comment: @Chris Gessler: "Queen of Diamonds and Queen of Diamonds" are not valid arguments though.

Comment: Method: AddCards(Card card); As long as I pass a valid card, it's a valid argument. However, if I called hand.AddCards(null); or hand.AddCards(new Card()); these would be invalid cards. If adding a valid card throws an exception on its own, the system should handle that outside the Hand class.

Comment: @Chris: `AddCards(new Card('Q','D')); AddCards(new Card('Q','D'))`: both instances passed are **valid cards**, but, if you don't want duplicates, the second is an **invalid argument**. "The passed arguments do not meet the parameter specification of the called method." It's not "a valid argument as long as you pass a valid card". It's a valid argument as long as you meet the parameter specification of the method.

Comment: I agree that it's an invalid card in terms of uniqueness within the hand, but the "Q of D" card is in fact valid as a card which does satisfy the argument.  In order to throw an ArgumentException, the AddCards() method would have to check for uniqueness. 99.99% of the time, the card will be unique (unless thre's a serious bug). So, checking for uniqueness 100% of the time to catch 0.01% errors is not efficient, neither is a try/catch in this scenerio.  Better to implement a keyed collection and let the collection throw an exception to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the deck's responsibility to ensure no duplicates when you create the deck of cards.  Deck creation could have multiple constructors for different games.

Comment: I agree the deck should ensure no duplicates and that's easy enough to accomplish, but that doesn't mean that the same unique card can't be passed to a hand more than once.

Answer (score 2):

If that is a typical situation that is *exceptional* and shouldn't happen ever, they throwing an exception might be the right thing to do. I would do everything you can to stop this from happening in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.

One thing you can consider is to prevent the scenario from even happening. I would have a `HandFactory` in which I could call `createHand(2)` where `2` is the number of cards to deal.

Inside `createHand` you deal yourself a single card, remove that card from a deck of 52, then randomly select another card. This way you can have Ah Ad, Ah Ac, Ah As etc. The deck would then be full again next time you call `createHand()`

In this example there are some obvious things I overlook like what happens if I deal 53 cards? I'll leave that for you to figure out. And this is not thread safe. Also Shuffle() doesn't really shuffle. One thing you could do in `Shuffle` is randomize the cards and change DealCard() to pick the Card off the top of the list instead.

**Example**

```
namespace StackOverflow_4599533
{
    public class Deck
    {
        private static Random sRand = new Random();

        private List<Card> mCards = new List<Card>();

        public Deck()
        {
            Shuffle();
        }

        public void Shuffle()
        {
            mCards.Clear();
            foreach (char suit in "DSCH") // Diamond, Spade, Clover, Heart
            {
                foreach (char rank in "1234567890JQK")
                {
                    mCards.Add(new Card(rank, suit));
                }
            }
        }

        public Card DealCard()
        {
            int cardIndex = sRand.Next(mCards.Count);
            Card card = mCards[cardIndex];
            mCards.Remove(card);
            return card;
       }
    }


    public class Card
    {
        public char r, s;

        public Card(char rank, char suit)
        {
            r = rank;
            s = suit;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "" + s + r;
        }
    }

    public class Hand
    {
        public Card c1, c2;

        public Hand(Card one, Card two)
        {
            c1 = one;
            c2 = two;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "C1: " + c1 + " C2: " + c2;
        }
    }

    public class Dealer
    {
        private Deck mDeck;

        public Dealer(Deck deck)
        {
            mDeck = deck;
        }

        public Hand DealHand()
        {
            return new Hand(mDeck.DealCard(), mDeck.DealCard());
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Deck deck = new Deck();
            Dealer dealer = new Dealer(deck);

            Hand hand1 = dealer.DealHand();
            Hand hand2 = dealer.DealHand();

            Console.WriteLine(hand1);
            Console.WriteLine(hand2);

            deck.Shuffle();

            hand1 = dealer.DealHand();
            hand2 = dealer.DealHand();

            Console.WriteLine(hand1);
            Console.WriteLine(hand2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Strategies**

If you wanted to really dive into the proper way to design this you can start using Strategies for dealing the cards, specialized decks, etc.

To truly prevent someone from creating an invalid hand consider what this code is doing

```
public interface Hand
{
    Card C1
    {
        get;
    }

    Card C2
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface Dealer
{
     Hand DealHand();
}

public class SpecialDealer : Dealer
{
    private Deck mDeck;

    private class HandImpl : Hand
    {
        private Card mC1;
        private Card mC2;

        public Card C1
        {
            get
            {
                return mC1;
            }
        }

        public Card C2
        {
            get
            {
                return mC2;
            }
        }

        public HandImpl(Card c1, Card c2)
        {
            mC1 = c1;
            mC2 = c2;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return C1 + " " + C2;
        }
    }

    public SpecialDealer(Deck deck)
    {
        mDeck = deck;
    }

    public Hand DealHand()
    {
        return new HandImpl(mDeck.DealCard(), mDeck.DealCard());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the best way to store the cards inside the factory? In a list?

Answer (score -1):

If the "Deck" object passes an identical card to an individual "Hand" object, this means that the state of the process is invalid.  The Hand object should use a keyed collection to store the cards, if a duplicate key is added to the collection, the collection itself will throw the exception for you.  So to answer the question, don't handle the error inside the Hand class.  Allow it to bubble up through the hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my first thought was to check for a duplicate and throw an exception, but that would be considered defensive coding.